# Laravel 5.5 Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php, laravel

```
public function __construct()
{
    view()->share('tags', DB::table('tags')->where('view', Auth::user()->view)->get());
    $this->middleware('auth');
}
```

I receive:

> (1/1) ErrorException
>   Trying to get property of non-object

Why? When I try to `return Auth::user()->view;` I got **2**. But when I manually type `->where('view', 2)` then everything is ok. How can I fix this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to return `gettype (Auth::user()->views)` to see if views its an integer. if not just `(int)Auth::user()->views` to make it.

or try to assign it to a variable like this:

```
$views = (int)(Auth::user()->views);
```

then use it ...`->where('view', $views)->get());`

Comment: You better change the field type to integer in your database or you might face the same problem again.

Answer (score 1):

you used auth middleware after **Auth::user()->view** , **it's wrong**

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth'); // firstly auth check , after that can use Auth::user() , before them Auth::user() return null   and you cant use ->view on null , when ErrorException Trying to get property of non-object
    view()->share('tags', DB::table('tags')->where('view', Auth::user()->view)->get());
}
```

your user is not signed please check

> Auth::check()

and after that use

> Auth::user()->view

Comment: Yeah I've checked. In __construct() I receive false. In another functions true.

Comment: on __construct please dd(Auth::user()) and see the result if return null , you must check the middlware